# probability of 1st order statistics is smaller than $x$ and 2nd order statistics is larger than $x$

Tags: order-statistics

Suppose that there $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ are drawn independently drawn according to a CDF $F$ and pdf $f$. 
Let $X_{(k;n)}$ be the $k$-th order statistics. so that we have $X_{(k;n)}\leq X_{(k+1;n)}$. Let's denote the CDF of $X_{(k;n)}$ by $F_{(k;n)}$.

Then what would be the probability that $X_{(1;n)}\leq x\leq X_{(2;n)}$? for some parameter $x\in \mathbb R$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it has a pdf, the distribution is continuous.  You're asking for the probability that exactly one of your sample is $\le x$, and by the binomial distribution this is $n F(x) (1-F(x))^{n-1}$.

Comment: No, I'm asking the probability of smallest sample is smaller than a certain value while the next smallest one is larger than the value.

Comment: @Andeanlll That is precisely what is being computed here. Note he says *exactly* one of the sample is $\le x.$

Comment: If exactly one is $\le x$, that one is the smallest, and the next smallest is $> x$,

Comment: Oh, that's right. I got that :) Thanks!